# MySQL - ORDER BY, CASE and DESC

Tags: mysql

I have a PHP variable called $var. I want to sort my result in dependence of $var. This one works:

```
$sql = "
SELECT
    myText1,
    myText2,
    someNumber
FROM myTable
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN $var = 1 THEN myText1
        WHEN $var = 2 THEN myText2
        WHEN $var = 3 THEN someNumber
    END";
```

But when $var is 3 I need to sort by `someNumber` with `DESC`. So I tried this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT
    myText1,
    myText2,
    someNumber
FROM myTable
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN $var = 1 THEN myText1
        WHEN $var = 2 THEN myText2
        WHEN $var = 3 THEN someNumber DESC
    END";
```

This one throws a syntax error. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split this into three `case` expressions:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN $var = 1 THEN myText1 END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN $var = 2 THEN myText2 END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN $var = 3 THEN someNumber END) DESC
```

The `ASC` is optional, of course -- there just to contract with the `DESC`.

More importantly, this removes the automatic conversion.  A `CASE` expression returns only one type.  When you mix different types, then some sort of conversion takes place.  That conversion can affect the ordering of the values.  This fixes that problem.

Comment: This also works with only one `CASE`.

Answer (score 1):

CASE only can return one expression, so you will have several cases:

```
CASE WHEN $var = 1 THEN myText1 END,
CASE WHEN $var = 2 THEN myText2 END,
CASE WHEN $var = 3 THEN someNumber END DESC
```

OR, optimized

```
CASE 
     WHEN $var = 1 THEN myText1,
     WHEN $var = 2 THEN myText2
END,
CASE WHEN $var = 3 THEN someNumber END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use math:

```
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN $var = 1 THEN myText1
    WHEN $var = 2 THEN myText2
    WHEN $var = 3 THEN 1000000 - someNumber
END
```